# Radical of a bimodule

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $R$ and $S$ be rings and suppose that $M$ is an $(R$-$S)$-bimodule. Consider the radical $rad( _RM)$ of $M$ viewed as a left $R$-module and the radical $rad( M_S)$ of $M$ viewed as a right $S$-module. Is it true that $rad( _RM) = rad( M_S)$?

If necessary, we may suppose that $M$ is finitely generated when viewed as a left $R$-module, and also when viewed as a right $S$-module.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple counterexample.

Consider any field $k$ and the rings $R := k[x] / (x^2)$ and $S := k$. Then $R$ itself is an $(R,k)$-bimodule, finitely generated over either one of these rings. As an $R$-module its radical is nontrivial, specifically generated by $x$. As a $k$-module the radical is $0$.